# Conveniently convert a View Controller object to Table View Controller during design time (Storyboard)

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uitableview, uistoryboard

I know I can just delete the original View Controller and drop a Table View Controller in it's place inside the Storyboard, but this requires that I re-establish the relationships between the before and after view controllers.

Is there an easier or more convenient way to convert the type of the object on the fly during design time? This seems like a very common task (at least in my own projects), and I would imagine that there is an option for that in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no UI in Xcode which lets you do this. You can however open the storyboard file in the xml editor (activating the version editor will do that) and change the name of the node from `<viewController ...>` to `<tableViewController ...>`. Don't forget to also change the closing tag to `</tableViewController>`.

Comment: I gave this a try on the latest Xcode (5.1) and it seems to fail validation and won't open. Haven't looked into why.

Comment: You do need to make addition adjustments, such as remove all the parameters related to `tableView` from the `<tableViewController ...>` bit. Then it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

What I did, is creating a UITableViewController in IB, open the Storyboard with a text editor, and copy all the nodes inside  from the UIViewController to the UITableViewController.

I think that with this way there's less risk of deleting something important.

Before copying the sections objects, make sure that both tableviews (UIViewController and UITableViewController) have the same properties set like: static or dynamic cells, style (plain or grouped), etc.

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me in converting a TableViewController to a normal ViewController. (kinda sad actually)

Comment: I converted from TableViewController to ViewController by simply changing <tableViewController> to <viewController> in text editor and it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, open the 'Utilities' pane (it appears from the right), click the 'Identity Inspector' and then in the 'Custom Class' region, select a different class.  Note, however, this won't change the view in the linked-to controller.  You'd need to remove the view and add a UITableView.  Might then have to establish some delegate connections.

I've done what you describe multiple times.  Sometimes I delete the target and start again; sometimes I do as I describe and convert 'by-hand.'

Comment: In trying to do the opposite conversion (TableViewController->ViewController), I'm able to delete the table view, but I'm not able to drop in a new regular View. I had to resort to hacking the XML.

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't exactly answer the question, but I think it may respond to the intent of the question.

The easiest way to replace a regular view controller and view with a table view controller and table view is to drag a table view controller from the objects menu to a blank section of canvas, creating a new scene. If the table view scene should be the first view of your app, drag the arrow pointing to the view controller scene to the new scene. Now, if there's nothing you need from the old view controller, just delete it.

See tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html).

However, probably what you actually want if you want to be able to drill-down into detail views from the table view is a navigation controller. The navigation controller object creates a table view scene by default as its root view controller.